# How to resolve Docker-Engine stopped issue on MAC-OS Ventura?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, macos-ventura, homebrew-cask

Docker-Desktop had stopped saying Docker Engine Stopped, tried resetting to Default but didn't work. So tried cleaning-up and setting up from scratch.

**Steps Followed:**

```
1) brew install --cask docker
2) docker --version
          Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
3) docker ps
          Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
4) docker run hello-world
          docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?. See 'docker run --help'.
5) sudo dockerd
Password:
        sudo: dockerd: command not found
6) brew services start docker                 
        Error: Formula `docker` is not installed.
 7) Accessing /Applications/Docker.app, quits immediately after launching and displaying that Docker Engine Stopped.
```

I tried above and couldn't start docker. Please let me know If anything wrong in steps followed. You can even suggest me to clean-up everything and set-up from scratch.

**Logs:**

```
==> Installing Cask docker
==> Moving App 'Docker.app' to '/Applications/Docker.app'
==> Linking Binary 'docker' to '/usr/local/bin/docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-desktop' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-ecr-login' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-osxkeychain' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-index' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-index'
==> Linking Binary 'hub-tool' to '/usr/local/bin/hub-tool'
==> Linking Binary 'com.docker.vpnkit' to '/usr/local/bin/vpnkit'
==> Linking Binary 'docker.bash-completion' to '/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker.zsh-completion' to '/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker.fish-completion' to '/opt/homebrew/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/docker.fish'
==> Linking Binary 'kubectl' to '/usr/local/bin/kubectl.docker'
==> Linking Binary 'com.docker.cli' to '/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli'
```

**NOTE : Apple M1 Pro, Ventura 13.5.2**

And also tried,

```
1) brew install docker   
2) docker --version
      Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
3) docker ps
       Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
4)brew services start docker                   
      Error: Formula `docker` has not implemented #plist, #service or installed a locatable service file
```

I kindly request you to help me here.

Comment: i would uninstall what you did with home-brew and just install the docker-desktop directly

Comment: You need to launch the Docker Desktop application before you can use any `docker` commands.  You can't independently manage the Docker daemon using _e.g._ `brew services`.

Comment: @DanielA.White : Thanks for responding. I really appreciate.
I uninstalled and downloaded docker-deskto for mac and moved it TO Application Folder. After opening Docker from Application, it says docker engine stopped. I really don't knpw how to debug or start this docker engine.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for responding. I really appreciate. I uninstalled and downloaded docker-deskto for mac and moved it TO Application Folder. After opening Docker from Application, it says docker engine stopped. I really don't knpw how to debug or start this docker engine.

Comment: Maybe the fIrewall?

Answer (score 0):

I have two almost identical MacBooks connected to the LAN. I suffered by the same problem - Engine Stopped message after fresh docker installation. Now, I have disconnected one of the MacBooks from the LAN (in fact I have shut it down) and (voila!) the docker is installed and running on the other one!
Version 4.24.0 (122432), Engine: 24.0.6